# Azure Block Blob Limitation

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Recently I ran into an error when I tried to backup a database to Azure Blob storage.  The error was this:

> 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.)

The database .mdf file was about 80gb.

Upon reading a few postings, it turns out Azure Blob storage does have some type of limitation.  If I understand correctly, there are only 50,000 blocks available and each block can hold roughly 4Mb.

I played around with the following BACKUP DATABASE TO URL with varying parameters:

1. `BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO URL WITH INIT` (failed)
2. `BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO URL WITH INIT, COMPRESSION` (succeeded)
3. `BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO URL WITH INIT, COMPRESSION, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304` (failed)
4. `BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO URL WITH INIT, COMPRESSION, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304, BLOCKSIZE = 65536` (succeeded)

When the operation was successful, the backup file produced was about 7.8Gb.  Again, the .mdf file was about 80Gb.

I'm a bit confused as to how the parameter `BLOCKSIZE` is used as part of the BACKUP T-SQL command.  Can someone explain why the operation would fail when this parameter is omitted?

Answer (score 4):

Azure Blob Storage has the following [blob and block size limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs):

The following table describes the maximum block and blob sizes permitted by service version.

| Service version | Maximum block size (via Put Block) | Maximum blob size (via Put Block List) | Maximum blob size via single write operation (via Put Blob) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Version 2019-12-12 and later | 4000 MiB | Approximately 190.7 TiB (4000 MiB X 50,000 blocks) | 5000 MiB (preview) |
| Version 2016-05-31 through version 2019-07-07 | 100 MiB | Approximately 4.75 TiB (100 MiB X 50,000 blocks) | 256 MiB |
| Versions prior to 2016-05-31 | 4 MiB | Approximately 195 GiB (4 MiB X 50,000 blocks) | 64 MiB |

As you noted in your question:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO URL WITH INIT, COMPRESSION
```

completed successfully, *without* the blocksize parameter.

Interestingly, I just attempted another backup, and received the 1117 error.  Looking at the SQL Server Error log, I see the following:

> Error: 3063, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> Write to backup block blob device https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/sql-backups/StackOverflowCS.bak failed. Device has reached its limit of allowed blocks.

<s>Since SQL Server 2019's maximum block size is 65536 bytes, and the maximum number of blocks per blob is 50,000, that equates to a maximum blob file size of 3,125 MB</s>.  SQL Server's `BLOCKSIZE=` parameter does not control the size of Azure Block Blob block sizes.  The only `BACKUP...` parameter that has any bearing on block size for backup to Azure is the `MAXTRANSFERSIZE` parameter.  Dimitri Furman talks about that in [this TechCommunity post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/backing-up-a-vldb-to-azure-blob-storage/ba-p/305441), where they mention:

> How can we make SQL Server use larger block sizes, specifically 4 MB blocks? Fortunately, this is as simple as using the MAXTRANSFERSIZE parameter in the BACKUP DATABASE statement. For 4 MB blocks, we used the following statement:
>
> ```
> BACKUP DATABASE … TO
> URL = 'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/backup/DB_part01.bak',
> …
> URL = 'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/backup/DB_part20.bak',
> WITH COMPRESSION, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304, BLOCKSIZE = 65536, CHECKSUM, FORMAT, STATS = 5;
> ```

I'm was able to backup a 150GB database to Azure Blob Storage using this statement:

```
BACKUP DATABASE StackOverflowCS 
TO URL = N'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/sql-backups/StackOverflowCS.bak'
WITH COPY_ONLY
    , STATS = 1
    , INIT
    , MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304
    , BLOCKSIZE = 512;
```

With compression, the backup consumed 81.2GB of space in a single file, and as you can see I did the backup with `BLOCKSIZE=512`.  Since that is the default blocksize, I could have left that parameter out.

Here's what the blob looks like in [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/):

[image]

To calculate the number of stripes you need for a given backup, you need to know the number of 4MB blocks SQL Server will create with the `MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304` parameter set.  Then divide that number by the maximum number of blocks per blob which is 50,000.  So for a backup that will consume 200GB, that's 214,748,364,800 bytes / 4194304 = 51,200.  Since 51,200 is slightly over the maximum of 50,000 blocks per blob, you'd need two stripes.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128944/discussion-on-answer-by-hannah-vernon-azure-block-blob-limitation).